# Why is the color of the image displayed on iOS17 leaning towards black

Tags: image, colors, xcode15, ios17

After upgrading to xcode15 and ios17, the image appears darker, which seems to only affect images with transparent channels.  Apple officials also have other developers who have encountered similar problems. As of now, does anyone have a good solution?  Apple official forum: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/733680 Apple official has not responded yet.

Comment: 哪个大佬遇到过这个问题或已经解决该问题？非常期待你们的回复，感谢

Comment: 我发现只有从 UIImage(named: "xxxx") 加载的有该问题，使用 UIImage(contentsOfFIle: "xxx") 加载时是没问题的，一定是苹果内部默认处理了什么

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple's bug on indexed color PNG. Effect iOS 17.0-17.2
See: https://github.com/dreampiggy/iOS17IndexedPNGDecodeBug